# AVPlayerViewController not deallocated/released

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

When the user clicks a button I show an AVPlayerViewController like this:

```
self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self presentViewController:self.playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [self.playerViewController.player play];
}];
```

The property `playerViewController` is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

I noticed that each time I press the button in my view controller to start the video playback the app consumes more memory. After profiling with Instruments I saw that the AVPlayerViewController instances are not being released, e.g. after starting the video twice I see this:

[image]

Base SDK: 9.3
Deployment Target: 8.3